# How do I create WordPress Authors Dropdown with links

Tags: author

I'm trying to create a dropdown of WordPress authors, with links to their author page.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_users(array('who'=>'authors')); ?>
```

I've got a similar dropdown for my archives, which is below (and works).

```
<select name="archive-dropdown" id="archives-dropdown--1" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Month' ) ); ?></option> 
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'option','show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>
</select>
```

Right now, the authors just show under the dropdown, but they don't link to their pages. I tried adapting the archive code to my author code, but I don't get anything to work. Here's what I was trying, but it doesn't work:

```
<select name="author-dropdown" id="author-dropdown--1" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Author' ) ); ?></option> 
<?php wp_dropdown_users(array('who'=>'authors')); ?>
</select>
```

I'm still pretty junior with my WordPress coding. Any insight would be great! I'm hoping I can help others if this gets solved for my situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong as I don't know how Wordpress controls the dropdown menu but looks like it could be only returning a name of the author and not a link to their page.

I have tested the below code in a Wordpress site environment and works including linking to the authors page.

```
   <select name="author-dropdown" id="author-dropdown--1" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Author' ) ); ?></option> 
<?php 
// loop through the users
$users = get_users('role=author');
foreach ($users as $user) 
{
    if(count_user_posts( $user->id ) >0)
    {
      // We need to add our url to the authors page
      echo '<option value="'.get_author_posts_url( $user->id ).'">';
      // Display name of the auther you could use another like nice_name
      echo $user->display_name;
      echo '</option>'; 
    } 

}
?>
</select>
```

[image: working]

Added update for making sure the authors have post and then added on administrator not sure how to combine the two roles without doing a duel foreach

```
<select name="author-dropdown" id="author-dropdown--1" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Author' ) ); ?></option> 
    <?php 
    // loop through the users
    $users = get_users('role=author');
    foreach ($users as $user) 
    {
        // get user who have posts only
        if(count_user_posts( $user->id ) >0)
        {
          // We need to add our url to the authors page
          echo '<option value="'.get_author_posts_url( $user->id ).'">';
          // Display name of the auther you could use another like nice_name
          echo $user->display_name;
          echo '</option>'; 
        } 

    }

$users = get_users('role=administrator');
    foreach ($users as $user) 
    {
        // get user who have posts only
        if(count_user_posts( $user->id ) >0)
        {
          // We need to add our url to the authors page
          echo '<option value="'.get_author_posts_url( $user->id ).'">';
          // Display name of the auther you could use another like nice_name
          echo $user->display_name;
          echo '</option>'; 
        } 

    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, however it didn't work. I only get the "Select Author" in the dropdown.

Comment: Updated my code and works in my live site.

Comment: Your correct! It works! Thank you! But what if one of my administrators created a post? Can admins also show? Can we hide authors or admins that have zero posts?

Comment: I have added a check for making sure they have posts and then run the code for admins as I don't know how to adde them into one foreach loop.

Comment: Sam, I appreciate all your help and insight. I know others will benefit from this post. I did quite a bit of searching before I posted here. Thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome! you could add a <option value="">Admins</option> above the admins foreach to state the users roles that are displayed if you wanted to make the menu more informal to people.

Answer (score 0):

A more "WordPress way" of doing it is to filter the output of the `wp_dropdown_users()` function instead of basically recreating the function.

In your theme or plugin, you want to add the filter immediately before you call `wp_dropdown_users()` and remove it immediately after to prevent unwanted side effects.

```
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users', 'wpse_260893_dropdown_users' );
wp_dropdown_users( [ 'who' => 'authors' ] );
remove_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users', 'wpse_260893_dropdown_users' );
```

Then you can place this in your plugin or theme functions.php.

```
//* Filter the output of wp_dropdown_users() function to replace user id with posts url
function wpse_260893_dropdown_users( $content ) {

  //* Find all cases where the option value is anything - (.*)
  $number_of_matches = preg_match_all( '/<option value=\'(.*)\'/', $content, $matches );

  //* If there's no matches, return early
  if( false === $number_of_matches || 0 === $number_of_matches ){
    return $content;
  }

  //* Get the author posts url for each of the matches found with preg_match_all()
  $posts_urls = array_map( function( $user_id ){
    return get_author_posts_url( $user_id );
  }, $matches[1] );

  //* Replace the author ids with their corresponding author posts url
  return str_replace( $matches[1], $posts_urls, $content );
}
```

Make sure to add the filter where you want to change the output of the `wp_dropdown_users()` function and remove it immediately after you don't need it anymore so that it doesn't affect anything else.

Comment: Nathan, thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate on what exactly the code is doing? I'm not so sure what it is doing.

Comment: Edited to hopefully make clearer what's going on. Cheers.